# How to access HttpServer on phone?

Tags: android, flutter, httpserver

I'm running a `HttpServer` instance on the simulator or the phone and cannot access it with the phone's/simulator's IP from the outside, only with http://localhost:3001 from the device.

Do I miss a configuration step or do I need another permission besides `android.permission.INTERNET`?

The current state is in this branch: https://github.com/elsamuko/clusterup/blob/features/LoadSaveJSON/lib/server.dart

Comment: Is the phone using wifi or its sim card?

Comment: I'm testing with WIFI.

Comment: Then the client can just use the local ip address of the server device. Assuming the client is in the same wifi network.

Comment: I tried to access the web server with the phone's IP and get no answer. It doesn't work from the dev computer or the phone itself.

Comment: `HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4`. Well you bound your server to localhost/127.0.0.1. Dont do that. You should not bind your server to any ip address to begin with.

Comment: You are right, `InternetAddress.anyIPv4` did the job. Thanks a lot.

Comment: PS: If you post your comment as answer, I'll mark it solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not bind your server to an ip address.

Let it float free.